# Puppeteer type on prompt

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, dom, puppeteer

Hello I am trying to login into something like this;

 The input fields can be translated into `username` and `password` and buttons are `login` and `cancel`.

I am trying to type on these fields and press on `login` button (blue one) 
 
 I have tried `await page.authenticate({ username: ... , password: ... })` 
Also I have tried `page.on('dialog', async (dialog) => .......)` but both of them are not working, it just stays like that.

Or how can I select those fields, i dont know if its even possible since its javascript based function.  
[image]

and here is my code;

```
import express from 'express';
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer'; 
import userAgent from 'user-agents'; 

const app = express();
 

const screenshot = 'github3.png';

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    executablePath: `C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe`,
    defaultViewport: null,
    args: ['--start-maximized'],
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setUserAgent(userAgent.toString());
  page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);
  await page.goto('myUrl...', {
    waitUntil: 'load',
    timeout: 0,
  });
  await page.click('#krbSubmit');

// AFTER THIS CLICK THE PROMPT OPENS ON THE NEXT PAGE

  //   await browser.close();
  res.send('hi');
});

app.listen('5000', console.log('server listening'));
```

Comment: Have you tried submitting the credentials in the URL directly? `page.goto("https://username:password@my.server/my/url")`

Comment: I cannot use that because the generated url after clicking on `#krbSubmit` is changing everytime.

Answer (score 1):

I have placed the `await page.authenticate({...})` to wrong place. Now, it can proceed. 
 Here is the final code;

```
import express from 'express';
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer'; 
import userAgent from 'user-agents'; 

const app = express();
const BLOCKLIST_URL = 'your_url';

const screenshot = 'github3.png';

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    executablePath: `C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe`,
    defaultViewport: null,
    args: ['--start-maximized'],
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setUserAgent(userAgent.toString());
  page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);
  await page.authenticate({ username: 'username', password: 'password' });

  await page.goto(BLOCKLIST_URL, {
    waitUntil: 'load',
    timeout: 0,
  });
  await page.click('#krbSubmit');

  //   await browser.close();
  res.send('hi');
});

app.listen('5000', console.log('server listening'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [request interception](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v14.1.1/docs/api.md#pagesetrequestinterceptionvalue) to inject the credentials into the request that the browser makes after clicking `#krbSubmit`, more precisely the request that brings up the login popup from your screenshot:

```js
await page.setRequestInterception(true);
page.on("request", (request) => {
  var url = request.url();
  if (<url is a generated login URL>)
    request.continue({
      url: url.replace("://", "://username:password@"),
      headers: {
        authorization: "Basic " + Buffer.from("username:password", "base64")
      }
    });
  else
    request.continue();
});
await page.goto('myUrl...', {
  waitUntil: 'load',
  timeout: 0,
});
await page.click('#krbSubmit');
```

One of the two injection methods (in the URL or in the `Authorization: Basic` header) should be sufficient.

This assumes that you can detect the generated login URL by a certain pattern. If that fails, you could consider other detection methods, such as counting requests: The first always goes to a fixed URL, the second to the login URL.

Comment: I logged request parameter to see if its even fired or not, unfortunately it does not fired. Actually this is a multi-page login. `#krbSubmit` selects a particular login path and according to that it generates a SAML request etc. First, I think I should focus on be able to type on the fields or even pressing on Enter via keyboard is sufficient. But still, `await page.keyboard.press('Enter')` does not work, the first input field comes as focused...

Comment: I have edited my answer and put an `await` before the `page.setRequestInterception(true);`. Does that help?

Comment: Unfortunately... `page.on('request', ....)` is not getting fired at all

Comment: I have added the solution, your way of thinking is true (Basic HTTP authentication) but I placed it into wrong place before